# Red black tree pseudocode redundancy

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree, clrs

In introduction to Algorithms Third Edition they have a pseudocode implementation of red-black tree deletion. Here it is...

```
RB-DELETE(T, z)
    y = z
    y-original-color = y.color
    if z.left == T.nil
        x = z.right
        RB-TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.right)
    elseif z.right == T.nil
        x = z.left
        RB-TRANSPLANT(T, z, z.left)
    else
        y = TREE-MINIMUM(z.right)
        y-original-color = y.color
        x = y.right
        if y.p == z
                x.p = y       // <--------- why????
        else
                RB-TRANSPLANT(T, y, y.right)
                y.right = z.right
                y.right.p = y
        RB-TRANSPLANT(T, z, y)
        y.left = z.left
        y.left.p = y
        y.color = z.color
    if y-original-color == BLACK
        RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
```

TREE-MINIMUM just finds the smallest value in a tree, RB-TRANSPLANT takes the parent of the second parameter and has it point to the third parameter, and has the third parameter's parent be the second parameter's parent.

By my comment, they test if y.p is z and if so set x.p to y. But x is already y.right, so this is like saying y.right.p = y, but y.right.p is already y! Why are they doing this?

Here is their explanation...

> “When y's original parent is z, however, we do not want x.p to point to y's original parent, since we are removing that node from the tree. Because node y will move up to take z's position in the tree, setting x.p to y in line 13 causes x.p to point to the original position of y's parent, even if x == T.nil.”

So they want to keep x's parent to be y...it already is y...

Comment: For "RB-TRANSPLANT takes the parent of the second parameter and has it point to the third parameter", no, it takes the parent of the third parameter to point to the second's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They state in the text that x can be also Nil, i.e. when y.right is Nil. It seems Nil is in this code also represented by a node, and they don't want to leave a dangling pointer.

Comment: Ah I see! Lightbulb. That was what they meant when they said they were going to take advantage of the fact that the T.nil node has left, right, and parent attributes. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify to others, T.nil is the node that represents all leaf nodes in the tree. Without it, you would have O(2^h) nil leaves, which is a waste of space. T.nil's attributes, left, right, and parent, are arbitrary. So when x = y.right, if x = T.nil, then x's parent will NOT be y. It needs to be set to y, if the last call RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x) is to work properly.