# CLRS red black tree deletion

Tags: red-black-tree, clrs

```
01 void RedBlackTree::deleteNode(Node *z)
02 {
03     Node *y = z;
04     Color yOriginalColor = y->color;
05     Node *x;
06     if (z->left == sentinel)
07     {
08         x = z->right;
09         transplant(z, z->right);
10     }
11     else if (z->right == sentinel)
12     {
13         x = z->left;
14         transplant(z, z->left);
15     }
16     else
17     {
18         y = minimum(z->right);
19         yOriginalColor = y->color;
20         x = y->right;
21         if (y->parent == z)
22         {
23             x->parent = y;  // WHY??
24         }
25         else
26         {
27             transplant(y, y->right);
28             y->right = z->right;
29             y->right->parent = y;
30         }
31         transplant(z, y);
32         y->left = z->left;
33         y->left->parent = y;
34         y->color = z->color;
35     }
36 
37     delete z;
38 
39     if (yOriginalColor == Color::BLACK)
40     {
41         deleteFixUp(x);
42     }
43 }
```

In line 20, we assign `y->right` to `x`. In line 23, we assign `y` to `x->parent`.
Isn't the assignment in line 23 redundant since the parent of `x` is `y` already?

In the book it says

> When y's original parent is z, however, we do not want x.p to point to y's original parent, since we are removing that node from the tree. Because node y will move up to take z's position in the tree, setting x.p to y in line 13 causes x.p to point to the original position of y's parent, even if x = T.nil.

I don't understand the explanation from the book, why would `x.p` points to `z`. When we move node `y` from its original position to `z`'s position, shouldn't `y`'s child `x` remain unaffected, still attached to `y`?

I come across 2 posts asking similar queations as I do, however, I'm still confused after reading through the answers.

- [red black tree pseudocode redundancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739730/red-black-tree-pseudocode-redundancy?rq=1)
- [issue with the red black delete algorithm mentioned in introduction to algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886679/issue-with-the-red-black-delete-algorithm-mentioned-in-introduction-to-algorithm)

After these 2 questions, I get one more question. I don't understand the assignment of `y` to `x.p` in line 23 has anything to do with `x` being the sentinel node (e.g. `T.nil`) or not.

Comment: The pseudo-code question's answer points out that if using an explicit sentinel node (as this code does) and y->right is the tree's sentinel then the parent value is not necessarily y (in fact, very likely is not), but that it needs to be for the following node removal to work.

Comment: Do you mean the sentinel node's parent needs to be `y` in order for *RB-DELETEFIXUP* to work properly?

Comment: That's what the comment in the answer to the pseudo-code answer says. When I've done RB trees I just went with an actual NULL value rather than a sentinel so haven't tried scanning through the code to confirm it.